# Using $_GET in a PHP array()

Tags: php, arrays, get, global, parameters

I have a PHP array:

```
$params = array(
  "name" => "$name",
  "description" => "not applicable", 
  "location" => "Orem Utah",
  "start_time" => "07/25/2013",
  "end_time" => "07/26/2013",
  "privacy_type" => "OPEN"
);
```

The only way I can get the `$name` array to work, is if I use strings such as "name"

`$name = $_GET['name'];` Does not work.

How do I properly put `$_GET` into this array?

Here's my entire code...

```
<?php

  session_start(); 
  $app_id = "xxxxxxx";
  $app_secret = "xxxxxxxx";
  $my_url = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.xxxx/xxxxxxxxxevent.php?name=".urlencode($_SESSION['name']).""; 

  $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

  if (empty($code)) {
    $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&scope=create_event";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
  }

  $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
  . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
  . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
  . "&code=" . $code;
  $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  $test = "$_GET[name]";
  $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?" . $access_token;
  $params = array(
    "name" => "$name",
    "description" => "not applicable", 
    "location" => "Orem Utah",
    "start_time" => "07/25/2013",
    "end_time" => "07/26/2013",
    "privacy_type" => "OPEN"
  ); 

  // Check if we have an image

  // Start the Graph API call
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $decoded = json_decode($result, 1);
  curl_close($ch);

  if (is_array($decoded) && isset($decoded['id'])) {
    $msg = "success";
  }
  $event_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/".$_SESSION['fid']."?" . $access_token;
  if (isset($msg)) {
    $_SESSION['fid'] = $decoded['id']; header("location:xxxxxx2.php");
  }

?>
<!-- irrelevant HTML BELOW HERE -->
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing this, but have you tried: array("name" => $name... just $name without the quotes? though it shouldn't matter

Comment: EDIT yes unquoted varibles do work.  $params = array("name" => $_GET['name'], "description" => "not applicable", "location" => "Orem Utah", "start_time" => "07/25/2013", "end_time" => "07/26/2013", "privacy_type" => "OPEN"); does not work... how would I achieve this?

Comment: @DavidEugenePeterson In what way does `$params = array("name" => $_GET['name']...` not work? Error message etc...?

Comment: I'm using: $params = array(name => $_GET['name'], "description" => "not applicable", "location" => "Orem Utah", "start_time" => "07/25/2013", "end_time" => "07/26/2013", "privacy_type" => "OPEN");

but i'm only able to submit events that contain 
1. One word
2. No symbols
..................................................
any thoughts behind why @DaveRandom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$params = array("name" => $name, "description" => "not applicable", "location" => "Orem Utah", "start_time" => "07/25/2013", "end_time" => "07/26/2013", "privacy_type" => "OPEN");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're attempting to concatenate in the variable as though you were building a SQL string or something...

```
$params = array("name" => '".$name.'",...
//-----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You need to be just using a simple variable here:

```
$params = array("name" => $_GET['name'],...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the string value out of the array.

First, is the GET being set?

If it is in the URL, it would look like this:
url.com/mypage.php?id=1

You can get it out of the URL this way.

```
$id = strval( $_GET['id'] );
echo 'ID: '.$id;  // check if it worked
```

If it is from a form, try:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $_GET ); echo '</pre>';
$name = $_GET['name'];  // If you can see it in the print_r, then this should work
```

If you have the get set, then in your array, you can set it like:

```
$myArray = array( 'id' => $id, 'name' => "Names" );
```

You do not need to use quotes.

Comment: I tried your method, but am recieving [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request.....removing file get contents shows that (id) aka (name) is registered properly to its corresponding varible.

However, still not posting to Fbook.

Comment: You deceived us good sir.  :P  You made us think you were novice, but your kind indicates otherwise.

Comment: I am betting you're getting the 400 because you don't have permission to get file contents (aka read) on that file.  I'm betting the file doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm referencing this line as the problem line.  $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);  I know $token_url is a URL but that doesn't mean he can read the contents there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that $_GET is actually passing a variable called 'name'? On your development box, add a line like:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($_GET,true).'<pre>';
```

and check that something is actually being passed.

The other thing I noticed is that your quotes are a bit screwed. You can either

- remove the quotes around $name : `array("name"=>$name...);`
- add the correct quotes if you need them :

  ```
  array("name"=>'"'.$name.'"'...)
  ```

  **or**

  ```
  array("name"=>"'{$name}'"...)
  ```

Finally, don't forget to escape the passed variables if you're going to use them in a database:

```
$name=mysql_escape_string($_GET['name']);
```

Hope this helps